# mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed

Tags: server, mysql

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-8.0 mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-client-8.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-8.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-8.0' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


sudo apt-get autoremove sudo apt-get autoclean

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Del thermald 2.4.9-1ubuntu0.3 [222 kB]

sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have unmet dependencies even though they are deleted. I don't get it.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have reinstalled an old snapshot to keep my sites online. So the old versions of mysql8.0 is installed again. I get unmet dependencies.

```
 apt policy mysql-common

mysql-common:
  Installed: 8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04
  Candidate: 8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04
  Version table:
 *** 8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04 500
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-8.0 amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.8+1.0.8 500
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages

dpkg -l | grep mysql

ii  dbconfig-mysql                         2.0.21                                      all          dbconfig-common MySQL/MariaDB support
ii  mysql-apt-config                       0.8.24-1                                    all          Auto configuration for MySQL APT Repo.
ii  mysql-client                           8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04                         amd64        MySQL Client meta package depending on latest version
ii  mysql-common                           8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04                         amd64        Common files shared between packages
ii  mysql-community-client                 8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04                         amd64        MySQL Client
ii  mysql-community-client-core            8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04                         amd64        MySQL Client Core Binaries
ii  mysql-community-client-plugins         8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04                         amd64        MySQL Client plugin
ii  mysql-community-server                 8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04                         amd64        MySQL Server
ii  mysql-community-server-core            8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04                         amd64        MySQL Server Core Binaires
ii  mysql-server                           8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04                         amd64        MySQL Server meta package depending on latest version
rc  mysql-server-5.7                       5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                     amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  php-mariadb-mysql-kbs                  1.2.12-1                                    all          Knowledge base about MariaDB and MySQL server variables
ii  php-mysql                              2:8.1+92ubuntu1                             all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php8.1-mysql                           8.1.2-1ubuntu2.13                           amd64        MySQL module for PHP


sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 https://repos.insights.digitalocean.com/apt/do-agent main InRelease
Get:4 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Hit:5 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fetched 270 kB in 1s (390 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


apt list --upgradable

Listing... Done
mysql-client/jammy-updates,jammy-security 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04]
mysql-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 8.0.33-1ubuntu18.04]

apt install mysql-client mysql-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-client-8.0 but 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
                Conflicts: mysql-client-core-8.0 but 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-8.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `apt policy mysql-common`

Comment: And pleased also `dpkg -l | grep mysql` and `sudo apt update`

Comment: I have edited my question with the output. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first restore [default repository](https://gist.github.com/hakerdefo/9c99e140f543b5089e32176fe8721f5f) for jammy.

Identify with

```
grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

where this repo
**repo.mysql.com** is active and remove it.

```
sudo apt -s purge $(dpkg -l | grep mysql | awk '{print $2}')
```

This is a simulation first.
For the complete remove.

```
sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l | grep mysql | awk '{print $2}')
```

refreshing package cache.

```
sudo apt update
```

Then try again.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! I also installed sudo apt-get install php-mysql and everything works like a charm, so nice! Thanks man! :)